# Python fancy strings

Tags: python, string, f-string

How can I use Python's fancy strings in this case?

Example:

I have a list of f-string in a consts.py file:

```
commands = [f"{prefix}...", f"{prefix}...", ...]
```

main.py:

```
import consts
consts.commands[0] = ...
```

Can I somehow set "prefix" in commands from main, or do I need to define  "prefix" first in consts and access it from main using consts.prefix = ...

Comment: f-strings are evaluated immediately to strings. All interpolation happens on the spot. So the value of `prefix` will be used **as it is** at the moment of creating your list.

Comment: They're called [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an f-string, the fields are evaluated immediately:

```
> x = 3
> f'x = {x}'
'x = 3'
```

If you want to defer the evaluation, use an ordinary `str` literal, and use the `format` method later.

```
> s = 'x = {x}'
> s
'x = {x}'
> s.format(x=3)
'x = 3'
```

Comment: f-string support also this more compact notation `f'{x = }'`